# Use bootstrap ability in node view's

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

Im working on new project with based on Node.js and for the view's Im using Jade ,I've added to the public folder (using express) the bootstrap.min.cssmy question is how should I add the bootsrtap jumbotron layout to the jade page.

I try like following but nothing happen,I want to add the toolbar on the upper side of the screen
with the about help etc

This is the layout

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
    body
        div.container
            block content
```

This is for example another page

```
extends layout

block content

h1= title
ul
    each flight, index in flights
        - flight = flight.getInformation()
        li= flight.number + ': ' + flight.origin + '-' + flight.destination
```

Update

I saw in some example that I should use something similar to but where should i put the referance to Jumbotron
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

```
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
  body
    block content
```